# static way of getting the resource of a file

Tags: java, javafx

Update:
I want to have the media player static but it does not work if i make is static.
Please note that the reason i want mediaPlayer static is that i want to access it from other classes.(the line is commented.)
This is my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;

public class Main extends Application {
    static boolean isSoundOn = false;
    static double soundVolume = .5;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(new Media(Main.class.getResource("song.mp3").toString()));

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    mediaPlayer.play();
    primaryStage.setTitle("duet by what");

//        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);


    //Group gamePaused = new Group();
    //Scene _gamePaused = new Scene(gamePaused, 1200, 700);
    //Group gameOver = new Group();
    //Scene _gameOver = new Scene(gameOver, 1200, 700);
    //Group game = new Group();
    //Scene _game = new Scene(game, 1200, 700);

    GUI gui = new GUI();
    primaryStage.setScene(gui.getMainMenu().getScene());
    primaryStage.show();
}
}

class GUI {
    private MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();



 public class MainMenu {
        private Scene scene;

        private MainMenu() {
            VBox vBox = new VBox();
            scene = new Scene(vBox, 400, 500);
            scene.getStylesheets().add("stylesheet.css");

            Label info = new Label(
                    "welcome the the what version\n" +
                            "of the well known Duet game!\n\n" +
                            "press \"I wanna play!\" to begin the game.\n\n" +
                            "please note that you can change\n" +
                            "the sound settings.");
            info.setId("info");
            vBox.getChildren().add(info);

            Button startGame = new Button("i wanna play right now!");
            startGame.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("game started!");
                }
            });
            vBox.getChildren().add(startGame);

            Label highScore = new Label("__highScore should be added here__");
            highScore.setId("highScore");
            vBox.getChildren().add(highScore);

            Button quitGame = new Button("get me out of this game!");
            quitGame.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("game quitted!");
                }
            });
            vBox.getChildren().add(quitGame);

            CheckBox soundOn = new CheckBox("soundOn?");
            Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip("if this box is checked, music will be played!");
            tooltip.setFont(new Font("Arial", 16));
            soundOn.setTooltip(tooltip);
            soundOn.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov,
                                    Boolean old_val, Boolean new_val) {
                    Main.isSoundOn = soundOn.isSelected();
                    System.out.println(Main.isSoundOn);
                }
            });
            vBox.getChildren().add(soundOn);

            HBox changeVolumeWrapper = new HBox();
            changeVolumeWrapper.setId("hBox");
            Label sliderLabel = new Label("sound volume: ");
            changeVolumeWrapper.getChildren().add(sliderLabel);

            Slider soundVolume = new Slider(0, 1, .5);
            soundVolume.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
                                    Number old_val, Number new_val) {
                    Main.soundVolume = new_val.doubleValue();
                    //Main.mediaPlayer.setVolume(Main.soundVolume);  here is why i need media player static.
                    System.out.printf("%.2f\n", Main.soundVolume);
                }
            });
            changeVolumeWrapper.getChildren().add(soundVolume);
            vBox.getChildren().add(changeVolumeWrapper);
        }

        public Scene getScene() {
            return scene;
        }
    }

    public MainMenu getMainMenu() {
        return mainMenu;
    }
}
```

Any other fixes to my code will be appreciated.
By the way, these are the errors i get:

> Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Toolkit not initialized   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:273)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:268)
>     at javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Platform.java:83)   at
>   javafx.scene.media.Media$_MetadataListener.onMetadata(Media.java:541)
>     at
>   com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.MetadataParserImpl.done(MetadataParserImpl.java:120)
>     at
>   com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.java.ID3MetadataParser.parse(ID3MetadataParser.java:237)
>     at
>   com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.MetadataParserImpl.run(MetadataParserImpl.java:103)
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:273)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:268)
>     at javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Platform.java:83)   at
>   javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:515)     at
>   javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.(MediaPlayer.java:414)   at
>   Main.(Main.java:22)   ... 3 more

Comment: Your MediaPlayer does not need to be static here. See the answer by James_D below. Avoid static variables wherever possible.

Comment: yes bc this is not my whole code i want to access this media player from other classes too:)

Comment: As I posted below, `static` has nothing to do with accessibility/visibility

Comment: @aran You realize that an object does not have to be static in order for it to be passed to other classes, right? static objects have very specific application and you should constantly avoid statically defined variables if you do not require them. Simply pass a reference to your sub objects that require access to the MediaPlayer object, in their constructors or via a method, if you wish. Static definition is completely unnecessary in this instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `getClass()` without an object for context is interpreted the same as any other instance method: `this.getClass()`.

In a static context, you can reference the class with `ClassName.class`; i.e. you can do

```
static URL resource = Main.class.getResource("a.mp3");
```

However, it is not at all clear in this scenario why you would want these variables to be static; only one instance of an `Application` subclass should ever be created per JVM instance, and these are inherently properties of that instance.

In the specific example in your (updated) question, I would define a separate class encapsulating the `MediaPlayer` and the other properties you currently make static. Note that `MediaPlayer` itself defines a `volume` property and a `muted` property. So you could do:

```
public class SoundPlayer {

    private final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ;

    public SoundPlayer(URL url) {
        this.mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(new Media(url));
    }

    public void play() {
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }

    public double getVolume() {
        return mediaPlayer.getVolume();
    }

    public void setVolume(double volume) {
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(volume);
    }

    public boolean isSoundOn() {
        return ! mediaPlayer.isMuted();
    }

    public void setSoundOn(boolean soundOn) {
        mediaPlayer.setMuted(! soundOn);
    }
}
```

Now your `Main` class can be:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(getClass().getResource("song.mp3"));
        soundPlayer.play();


        primaryStage.setTitle("duet by Aran Mohyeddin");

        GUI gui = new GUI(soundPlayer);

        primaryStage.setScene(gui.getMainMenu().getScene());
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

and update your `GUI` and `MainMenu` classes to have a reference to a `SoundPlayer`:

```
public class MainMenu {
        private Scene scene;

        private final SoundPlayer soundPlayer ;

        private MainMenu(SoundPlayer soundPlayer) {

            this.soundPlayer = soundPlayer ;

            // existing code omitted...

            CheckBox soundOn = new CheckBox("soundOn?");
            Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip("if this box is checked, music will be played!");
            tooltip.setFont(new Font("Arial", 16));
            soundOn.setTooltip(tooltip);
            soundOn.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov,
                                    Boolean old_val, Boolean new_val) {

                    soundPlayer.setSoundOn(new_val);
                }
            });

            // ...


            Slider soundVolume = new Slider(0, 1, .5);
            soundVolume.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
                                    Number old_val, Number new_val) {

                    soundPlayer.setVolumn(new_val.doubleValue());
                    System.out.printf("%.2f\n", Main.soundVolume);
                }
            });
            changeVolumeWrapper.getChildren().add(soundVolume);
            vBox.getChildren().add(changeVolumeWrapper);
        }

        public Scene getScene() {
            return scene;
        }
    }

    public MainMenu getMainMenu() {
        return mainMenu;
    }
}
```

Also note that if you expose the actual property objects from `SoundPlayer`, for example:

```
public class SoundPlayer {

    private final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ;

    // ...


    public DoubleProperty volumeProperty() {
        return mediaPlayer.volumeProperty();
    }

    // ...
}
```

then you can simplify some of your code:

```
    Slider soundVolume = new Slider(0, 1, .5);
    // instead of the listener, just do:
    soundPlayer.volumeProperty().bindBidirectional(soundVolume.valueProperty());
```

(Converting the `mutedProperty` to a `soundOnProperty` is a little less elegant.)

Comment: great thanks! well i just want to access media player from other classes without encapsulation and passing the instance of main bc i think the media player should also be final

Comment: static has nothing to do with accessing fields and is completely independent of whether or not a field is final. It is very bad practice to make a variable static just to avoid enforcing proper encapsulation.